# how to list all tags xml in node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xml-parsing, fs

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 1 = video , 2 = html , 3 = pdf -->
<stage_type>2</stage_type>
<resource_name>http://www.XXX</resource_name>
```

I want to get `<resource_name>`. I'm using **xml2js**.
When I use:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
                        fs.readFile('./' + file, function(err, data) {
                            parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                                console.dir(result);
                                console.log('Done');
                            });
                        });
```

I got `<stage_type>` and no all xml file. (`<stage_type>` and `<resource_name>`).
I know that I don't have a root tag, but I need to leave it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file isn't valid XML.  It has multiple root nodes. Try parsing XML like this and it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 1 = video , 2 = html , 3 = pdf -->
<resource>
  <stage_type>2</stage_type>
  <resource_name>http://www.XXX</resource_name>
</resource>
```

You could rename that `resource` node to whatever you want, but that's why `xml2js` is missing the `resource_name`.  I don't know of any option to have `xml2js` process a fragment (which might make it accept this type of XML).